How to configure a Laravel project that resides in a domain's subfolder
I have deployed a Laravel 11 project to the subfolder of a domain.
I updated the index.php and the site loads properly.
However, when I call the redirect method within controllers, it navigates to the root folder, and not to the subfolder.
On the server, the folder structure is as follows:
This is the publicly accessible site:
/public_html/herbarium

And this is where the Laravel project resides and which includes the vendor folder (not accessible via the browser):
/<laravel-project> 

I have set the APP_URL in the .env file to reflect the subfolder but that does not seem to affect anything.
I have an htaccess file in the following location /public_html/ and have tried a few rewrite rules suggested on the internet, but need help with this.
Currently the htaccess file has the following code:
After the line: "RewriteEngine On" I have two "RewriteRule" lines that I tried, but those did not work, and I have therefore commented them out. The subfolder name is "herbarium"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /herbarium/$1 [L]
    #RewriteBase /apps/herbarium/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
    
</IfModule>


Instead of making the site available through <domain.name>/herbarium/
I decided to use a subdomain like this: herbarium.<domain.name>
Much simpler to set up for me as there is no htaccess configuration involved...
